# Disable DataContext for VS Disigner

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to disable the creation of the DataContext instance within the WPF designer (in VS not blend).
What I've done so far is the following code:

```
<Window ....
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Class1, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:Class2 d:IsDesignTimeCreatable="False/>
    </Window.DataContext>
</Window>
```

While the data from Class1 is used in during designtime, an instance of Class2 is still being created.

I know I could use some code to check if I am in designtime, but I want to solve this via XAML only!

Any Suggestions?

Comment: You have a typo :) d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Class1, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}" and d:IsDesignTimeCreatable="False" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the attached property `DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode`. Here are a few suggestions but none of them seems very clean and in the end, I think using a couple of lines in code is the easiest solution.

- I don't think the `DataContext` object gets instantiated if it's set in the `Style` (but that could change in a future upgrade of VS Designer)
- You could bind `DataContext` to `IsInDesignMode` with a Converter that returns an instance of `Class2` or null depending on the value of `IsInDesignMode`
- Use a `DataTrigger`. Only Xaml but way to much code..

*Example*

```
<Window ...
        xmlns:pf="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=PresentationFramework">
    <Window.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Window">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                      Path=(pf:DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode)}"
                    Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="DataContext">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <local:Class2 />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Style>
    <!--...-->
</Window>
```

Comment: I don't like code behind for that. Style + Triggers was still a great idea. Still DataTrigger is incorrect, it should be Trigger. Further you should outsource the Style into a ResourceDictionary, otherwise the designer tends to create an instance of the datacontext if you click on the <local:Class2/> node within the xaml.